# how to know outlook appointment created and sent using EWS

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS Managed API to create outlook appointment but in some case when any one of the attendee email id is wrong then i got notification on outlook that notification not sent to this attendee(wrong one) but not through api.

So, is there any way to check if meeting successfully sent to all attendees?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633661(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: If you don't know, we know even less without seeing some code. How do you catch errors returned? Edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that in Outlook, you received an **NDR message**. The EWS Managed API will not receive notifications unless you implement EWS notifications. Your description mentions nothing about using EWS notifications.  I suggest you read [Notification subscriptions, mailbox events, and EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn458791%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) for more information. Your calls to create meetings with attendees won't provide notifications about identities that don't resolve to a user in an organization. That information is provided by Exchange after it tries to resolve the identities. You have to options, and in fact, you may want to implement both depending on your scenario:

1. Use the ExchangeService.ResolveName method on each attendee id before you try to create an appointment with attendees. This will make sure that you either have, or can locate, a valid attendee in your Exchange organization. If the attendee might be outside you Exchange organization, then this won't help. Then you will have to use EWS notifications.
2. Implement EWS notifications. If Exchange tries to send the email and it comes back as undeliverable, Exchange will put an NDR message in the caller's inbox. You can use notifications to know when messages arrive in the inbox, and then you can inspect it to determine if it is an NDR message.

I hope this helped.